# Strange behaviour in C programming

Tags: c

The program bellow is supposed to do two things. First is to reverse a string and the second is to find in that string the most and the least seen character. It works almost fine. The results are correct but on finishing it does not return 0 and second if I delete the line 16 `puts("\n")` the program does not work. That specific line obviously does nothing, but without it, it does not work. I tried to replace it with `fflush(stdin)` but it did not work. I do not get it. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void chars(char *s, char *most_seen, char *less_seen)
{
    int letters[26] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        char c = *(s + i);
        letters[(int)c - 97]++;
    }

    puts("\n");
    int maxLetter = 0;
    int minLetter = 0;
    int posMax = 0, posMin = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if (letters[i] > maxLetter)
        {
            maxLetter = letters[i];
            posMax = i;
        }
        if (letters[i] < minLetter)
        {
            if (letters[i] == 0) continue;
            minLetter = letters[i];
            posMin = i;
        }
    }
    *most_seen = posMax + 97;
    *less_seen = posMin + 97;
}

char *reverse(char *s)
{
    char *reversed = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char));
    fflush(stdin);
    int i = 0, size = strlen(s) - 1;
    for (; i < strlen(s); i++)
        reversed[i] = s[size--];
    reversed[i] = '\0';

    return reversed;
}

int main()
{
    char *s = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    char *s2;

    char mostSeen, lessSeen;

    gets(s);
    chars(s, &mostSeen, &lessSeen);
    s2 = reverse(s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    printf("%s\n", s2);
    printf("%c %c\n", mostSeen, lessSeen);

    free(s);
    free(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what happens when the program doesn't work. And what return code is it returning if not zero?

Comment: Try 'malloc(strlen(s)*sizeof(char));' ->   'malloc((strlen(s)+1)*sizeof(char));'.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you can just remove that wherever you use it. You should also read through [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) and [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: You should store the result of strlen(s)

Comment: When i remove puts() then the program does not print anything and on finishing it gives a garbage number instead of 0. The problem is not on reverse function but in chars function.

Comment: I see you are using `gets`. You should **never** use that function. I'm not sure where you got that from. Use a different source to learn from.

Comment: `gets` has been removed completely from newer C standards [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). And never call `strlen` in a loop like that. Store the result in a variable and reuse it

Comment: Thank  you. I replaced it with fgets() and it works now. I did not know that it has been removed from C standards.

Comment: Your `fflush(stdin)` is useless, since `fflush` is for *output* `FILE` streams

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- [major] you do not allocate enough space for the reversed string: you must allocate one extra byte for the null terminator.
- [major] the initializer `int letters[26] = {};` is invalid in C. You probably compile the code as C++, where this syntax is allowed, but beware that C++ is a different language, not a strict superset of C.
- [major] you should test if the character from the string is between `'a'` and `'z'` before incrementing `letters[(int)c - 97]`. As coded, you have undefined behavior if the string contains any character outside the range `97..122`.
- [major] the second loop in `chars()` should run from `i = 0` to `i < 26`.
- [major] you initialize `minLetter` to `0`, so the test `if (letters[i] < minLetter)` will always evaluate to false. You should instead initialize `minLetter` to the length of the string plus one.
- [minor] you compute the length of the string too many times. You should store it in a local variable.
- [style] the syntax `*(s+i)` is valid, but it is much more readable to write `str[i]`.
- [style] you should use `'a'` instead of `97`, both for portability and readability.
- [major] the function `gets()` has been removed from the C Standard because there is no way to tell the C library the size of the array, so any sufficiently long input line will cause undefined behavior (buffer overflow). Use `fgets()` instead and remove the trailing newline.
- [minor] there is no need to allocate `s`: make it a local `char` array (automatic storage).
- [minor] there is no need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C, but it is mandatory in C++.
- [minor] the size of `char` is `1` by definition in C.
- [major] you do not check for memory allocation failure.
- [minor] if the string is empty, you return `'a'` as the most and least frequent letter, which is incorrect.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t chars(const char *s, char *most_seen, char *least_seen) {
    /* only count lowercase letters */
    size_t counts['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0 };
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int c = s[i];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            counts[c - 'a']++;
    }

    size_t maxCount = 0, minCount = len + 1;
    char maxLetter = 0, minLetter = 0;

    for (int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
        size_t count = counts[i - 'a'];
        if (count != 0) {
            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                maxLetter = c;
            }
            if (count < minCount) {
                minCount = count;
                minLetter = c;
            }
        }
    }
    *most_seen = maxLetter;
    *least_seen = minLetter;
    return len;
}

char *reverse(const char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *reversed = malloc(len + 1);
    if (reversed != NULL) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            reversed[i] = s[len - i - 1];
        }
        reversed[len] = '\0';
    }
    return reversed;
}

int main() {
    char s[1000];
    char *s2;
    char mostSeen, leastSeen;

    if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
        /* strip the trailing newline, if any */
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        if (len > 0 && s[len - 1] == '\n') {
            s[--len] = '\0';
        }
        printf("%s\n", s);
        s2 = reverse(s);
        if (s2 == NULL) {
            printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", s2);
            free(s2);
        }
        if (chars(s, &mostSeen, &leastSeen) == 0) {
            printf("string is empty.\n");
        } else {
            printf("%c %c\n", mostSeen, leastSeen);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very  much for your comprehensive answer. You helped me understand many subjects. I wish my university professors were like you.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DimitriosKonstantinidis: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.